# jquery + html get

Tags: jquery, html, class

I want to know how to make something like this:

example:

`<a href="#" id="123">Link</a>`

And when I click on it I want to get `id=123` with jQuery or something similar.

And then add this `id=123` to another div:

Like this

`<div class='info'>id=123</div>`

Can you help me?

Comment: did you try anything by yourself? like a javascript or even a jquery tutorial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could subscribe to the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event of all anchors (or narrow them down by using a CSS class selector) and inside this event fetch the id of the anchor that was clicked and use it to set the html of the target div:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        // this will contain the id of the anchor that was clicked
        var id = this.id;
        $('.info').html('id=' + id);
    });
});
```

Comment: and: .html('id=' + id); for the actual string "id=123".

Comment: @Oyeme, the OP's link had `href="#"` so returning false is not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$('#123').click(function(){ 
    $('div.info').html('id=' + this.id);
    return false; 
});
```

Keep in mind however that "123" is an invalid DOM id. It should begin with a letter such as "a123".

Comment: Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/BfwRs/